# Symfony: how to create forms dynamically in a foreach loop

Tags: symfony

I have a form that contains a hidden field, it uses this field to send a variable that indicates the id of the item to remove, to the action. I have a table that displays the content of the database table 'profil', for every line there is a button "supprimer" that deletes this line, but as i said, it only deletes the first line. Apparentlu this loop creates only one form for the first item, so I want to create this form for every item in the table.

```
 {% if profils %}
           <div id="prof_table">
            <table style="background-color: #f9f9f9;position: absolute;top:10vmin;left: 5vmin;"
                   class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Identificateur </th>
                    <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Libellé</th>
                    <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Actions</th>
                </tr>
                {% for profil in profils %}
                <tr><td>{{ profil.id }}</td><td>{{ profil.libelle }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                            <a data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content3" href="javascript:;"
                               style="color: #ffffee;text-decoration: none;">Supprimer</a>
                        </button>
                    </td></tr>

                    <!-- HERE IS THE POPUP FORM TO DELETE PROFILES-->
                    <div style="display: none; height: 40vh; width: 30vw;" id="hidden-content3">
                        <span style="position:relative;top:10vmin;font-size: medium;"></span>
                    {% if form3 %}
                            <label style="display:inline-table;">
                                <span style="font-size: medium;">Etes vous surs de vouloir supprimer ce profil?</span>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        {{ form_start(form3, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}
                        <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                            <label style="display:inline-table;">
                                <span>{{form_widget(form3.idprof, {attr: { value : profil.id}} )}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                            <span>{{ form_widget(form3.Confirmer)  }}</span>
                        </section>
                        {{ form_end(form3) }}
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
           </div>
        {% else %}
                {{ "Aucun profil n'a été trouvé." }}
        {% endif %}


  /**
     * @Route("/webmaster/gestProf/{idprof}",  defaults={"idprof": 0},name="gestProf")
     * Method ("POST")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function gestProfAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        $em=$this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:profil");
        $profils = $repository->findAll();


        foreach ($profils as $prof) {
            $id = $prof->getId();
            $libelle = $prof->getLibelle();

        }
        $prof = new profil();
        $form3 = $this->createFormBuilder($prof, array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->setMethod("POST")
            ->add('idprof', 'hidden', array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('Confirmer', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn', 'id' => 'login_btn',
                'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
            ->getForm();
             $form3->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form3->isSubmitted()) {
            //$idprof = $request->request->get('idprof');
            $idprof = $form3->get('idprof')->getData();
            $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:profil");
            $prof = $repository->findOneById($idprof);

                $em=$this
                    ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();
                $em->remove($prof);
                $em->flush();
            }

        var_dump($request->getContent());
        return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:gestProf.html.twig', array('profils'=>$profils,
             'form3'=>$form3->createView()

        ));
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can create the form like that in the for loop, check your code with inspect element first if the forms are being created ok, maybe that's the reason it is deleting only the first line because the form is being created only the first time on the loop. @Susan

Comment: yeah alright, i know my fault, but i don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: One way to do this, like this [Delete one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036544/symfony2-delete-record-from-table) I hope it helps

Comment: okay thnx, but this won't help because it does almost the same thing i do. There is nothing there that mentions how can i use a form and send a request inside a foreach loop